# what would be the possible approach to go : SQS or SNS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am going to make the rails application which integrates the Amazon's cloud services.

- I have explore amazon's SNS service which gives the facility of public subscription which i don't want to do. I want to notify only particular subscriber.  
  For example if I have 5 subscriber in one topic then the notification should be goes to particular  subscriber.

  I have also explored amazon's SQS in which i have to write a poller which monitor the queue for message. SQS has also a lock mechanism but the problem is that it is distributed so there would be a chance of getting same message from another copy of queue for process.

I want to know that what would be the possible approach to go.

Comment: It would help if you described your scenario a little more clearly.  Why do you need to send messages at all?  Why can't your client just call your Ruby webservice directly? (ie, what motivator is driving you to "indirect" messaging)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SQS sounds like what you want.

You can run multiple "worker" processes that compete over messages in the queue.  Each message is only consumed once.  The logic behind the "lock" / timeout that you mention is as follows: if one of your workers were to die after downloading a message, but before processing it, then you want that message to eventually time out and be re-downloaded for processing on another node.

Yes, SQS is built on a polling model.  For example, I have a number of use cases in which I use a minutely cron job to poll for new messages in the queue and take action on any messages found.  This pattern is stupid simple to build and works wonders for a bunch of use cases -- a handy little "client" script that pushes a message into the queue, and the cron activated script that will process that message within a minute or so.

If your message pattern is extremely sparse -- eg, only a few messages a day -- it may seem wasteful to poll constantly while the queue is empty.  It hardly matters.

My original calculation was that a minutely cron job would cost $0.04 (now $0.02) per month.  Since then, SQS added a "Long-Polling" feature that lets you achieve sub-second latency on processing new messages by sending 1 "long-poll" message every 20 seconds to poll an idle queue.  Plus, they dropped the price 50%.  So per month, that's 131k messages (~$0.06), a little bit more expensive, but with near realtime request processing.

<strike>Keep in mind that a minutely cron job I described only costs ~$0.04 / month in request load (30d*24h*60m * 1c / 10k msgs).  So at a minutely clip, cost shouldn't really be a concern here.  Even polling every second, the price rises only to $2.59 / mo, not exactly a bank buster.</strike>

<strike>However, it is possible to avoid frequent polling using a webservice that takes an SNS HTTP message.  Such an architecture would work as follows: client pushes message to SNS, which pushes message to SQS and routes an HTTP request to your webservice, triggering it to drain the queue.  You'd still want to poll the queue hourly or daily, just in case an HTTP request was dropped.  In the end though, I'm not sure I can think of any scenario which really justifies such complexity.  I'd much rather pay $0.04 a month to have a dirt simple cron job polling my queue.</strike>

Comment: who downvoted me?  If you are going to down-vote, please have the courtesy to leave a comment indicating which part of my answer you find insufficient...

Comment: would latency be a reason to build the system you've described (using SNS and SQS)? If you wanted your message to be processed as fast as possible (ie, 1sec delay is far too long), would this be the way to go?

Comment: reading further, is all this superseeded by AWS "Long-Polling" ?

Comment: @mcmillab Long-polling a SQS queue means waiting up to 20 seconds for a message to arrive, rather than disconnecting immediately if no messages are available. All it changes is that you only need to make a new request once every 20 seconds to minimize latency.

Comment: @mcmillab - as benzado says, Long-polling was created precisely to make this scenario more efficient.  You can achieve great sub-second latency with 1 call every 20 seconds.  Plus, there's been a substantial price drop since I wrote this.  So yeah, using SNS is totally not worth it anymore.